# Eclipse, PyDev, PySide, importing, and parsing

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, nuke

I am working in Eclipse but running my code in Nuke. Nuke uses PySide, but it's built into Nuke so Eclipse can't parse it. I cannot install PySide in my environment (VFX studio rules) but I do have PyQt4. So I can change my import from PySide to PyQt4 and it parses correctly in Eclipse - but it will error when loading Nuke. So what I need is a way to get Eclipse/PyDev to use PyQt4 while Nuke uses PySide. I thought perhaps I could use PyDev's String Substitution scheme but either it doesn't do what I want or I'm not using it right. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Den

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Rob's qtshim.py.

You'll find it here: https://github.com/rgalanakis/practicalmayapython/blob/master/src/chapter5/qtshim.py

Import `QtCore`, `QtGui` etc. From `qtshim` instead of PySide or PyQt. Code written with this will work for both environments.

I use my own version of something like this to work with PyQt and PySide.

Hope that was useful.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I only need the code hinting/parsing in Eclipse to work, which is the only place I need the PyQt4 code to load. Looking at the code, it's just a fancy try/except, so perhaps Eclipse will "try" the PySide and if it doesn't load during the parse use the PyQt4... I never tried that because I didn't think it would work. Will test it!

Comment: Yes we use it in the animation industry. This code is from a leading author. Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it was useful! All the best.

Comment: And yes, sometimes a fancy try except is all you need.

Comment: Add your PyQt location to interpreter path and code hinting should kick in.

Comment: So far, just adding Try (PySide) with Except (PyQt4) seems to work in both environments. The PySide doesn't have any hinting info in Eclipse but the PyQt4 does, while in Nuke the PySide loads properly. Should have tried it! Thanks, kartikg3.